# How to generate matplotlib animation generated by many subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot

I have code that generates graphs of a propagating gausian. Each plot `plt.plot(r, Sevol[0])` generates an image of the type:

[image]

Many subplots at the same figure generetes the image above:

```
plt.plot(r, Sevol[0])
plt.plot(r, Sevol[10])
plt.plot(r, Sevol[20])
plt.plot(r, Sevol[30])
plt.plot(r, Sevol[40])
```

[image]

I want to make an animation where I can plot each image generated by one `plt.plot(r, Sevol[i])` at a time, so that the previous one is superimposed by the next one.

```
fig = plt.figure()

plt.xlabel('r')
plt.xlabel('S')
plt.grid()
#plt.plot(r, Sevol[0])
#plt.plot(r, Sevol[2])
#plt.plot(r, Sevol[3])
#plt.plot(r, Sevol[4], color='C1', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
#plt.plot(r, Sevol[5], color='C0', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
#plt.plot(r, Sevol[6], color='C1', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
plt.xlim(ri, rf)

graph, = plt.plot([], [], color='gold', markersize=3)

def animate(i):
  graph.set_data(r[:i], Sevol[:i])
  return graph,

skipframes = int(len(r)/200)
if skipframes == 0:
    skipframes = 1  

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=range(0,len(r),skipframes), interval=10, blit = True, repeat = False)

ani
```

Comment: Does removing the `return` statement in `animate` help?

Comment: You may want to update the code to become a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that could help others to help you.

Comment: maybe  inside `animate` use `plot(r[:i], Sevol[:i])` to plot new data from list. Don't use `graph.set_data(r[:i], Sevol[:i])` because it replace previous plot.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `animate(i)` function to return the graph every frame, you can just call `plt.plot()` for each of the lines you are trying to display.

Removing the `skipframes` variable/loop can also make it a bit more clear what the `frames` value in `FuncAnimation` is supposed to be.

> NOTE: This isn't the most efficient approach, but as long as you are plotting relatively few samples you won't have any lagging issues in the animation.

```
#################### DELETE THIS #######################
graph, = plt.plot([], [], color='gold', markersize=3)

def animate(i):
    graph.set_data(r[:i], yLst[:i])
    return graph,

skipframes = int(len(r)/200)
if skipframes == 0:
    skipframes = 1

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=range(0,len(r),skipframes), interval=10, blit = True, repeat = False)

#################### INSERT THIS #######################
def animate(i):
    numPlots = i //10    # how many plots (-1) will be shown based on the frame.
    for n in range(numPlots):
        plt.plot(r[n], Sevol[n], color='gold', markersize=3)

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100, interval=10, blit = True, repeat = False)
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes, but I still got the error ```RuntimeError: The animation function must return a sequence of Artist objects.```. Should I put a return in the function? I'm using google colab

Comment: What happens when you use `blit=False` when you call the animation? That might fix your issue.